# How to get list of checked checkboxes in form using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have a form which have many check boxes in it. User will check one or many checkboxes and click on submit butten. So How could I get the list and count of the input box which are checked.

Please guide me friends.

Comment: There are quite some similar questions, so try one of their answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+checkbox+list

Comment: this has been asked so many times... please do a search before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// will give all the checked checkboxes in an array
var checkedCheckBoxes = $("input:checkbox:checked"); 
var checkedLength = checkedCheckBoxes.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little ambiguous. If you want a list of all checkboxes & the count of checked ones:

```
$cb = $(':checkbox');
numChecked = $cb.filter(':checked').length;
```

However, if you want a list of just the checked checkboxes, and the count of that:

```
$cb = $(':checkbox:checked');
numChecked = $cb.length;
```

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was down voted. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

```
numChecked = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
```